# reading data from CSV file inserting into MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Getting following error when am inserting datetime combined

> column._mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime
>   value: '8/13/2017 19:10' for column 'js_signup' at row 1")

and my datetime is "8/13/2017 19:10" in this format.

```
 import csv
 import MySQLdb
 mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='Yogi123$',db='wisdom_india')
 cursor = mydb.cursor()
 csv_data = csv.reader(file('test_csv.csv'))
 for row in csv_data:
     cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(js_id, \
      js_name,js_email,js_signup )' \
      'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', 
      row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Comment: someone please help me with this

Comment: You can use the [LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command to load the data as fast as possible instead of reading and writing rows one by one. One of the comments in the documentation page shows how you can parse dates while loading with a `SET` clause, eg `set 
col3 = str_to_date(@col3, '%m/%d/%Y');`